# PHP array to javascript conversion altering the index values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a javascript function which gets user info from database via ajax. It has following code.

```
var temp_id = new Object;
function checkRequests() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "bin/inc/classes/mechanism_class.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'checkrequest': '1'},
        success: function(data1) {
            for(var i=0; i<jQuery.parseJSON(data1).length; i++) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"bin/inc/classes/mechanism_class.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'checkrequest2': jQuery.parseJSON(data1)[i]},
                    success: function(data) {
                        requestPopper(data);
                    }
                }).error(function() {

                });
            }

        }
    }).error(function() {

    });
}

function requestPopper(data) {
    var id = jQuery.parseJSON(data)[0];
    var firstname = jQuery.parseJSON(data)[1];
    var lastname = jQuery.parseJSON(data)[2];
    var imagedir = jQuery.parseJSON(data)[3];
    var imageext = jQuery.parseJSON(data)[4];
    var imgsrc = 'uploads/'+imagedir+'/'+'thumbs/'+imagedir+'size2.'+imageext;
    if($('#'+'requests_content_'+id).length == 0) {
        if($('.requests_content').length == 0) {
            $('#requests').after('<div id="dropdown_1"><div class="requests_content" id="requests_content_'+id+'"><a href='+'profile.php?user='+id+'><img src='+imgsrc+' width="60" height="60" class="senders_image"></a><a id="senders_name" href='+'profile.php?user='+id+'>'+firstname + ' ' +lastname+'</a><div id="acceptbutton">Accept</div><div id="rejectbutton">Reject</div></div></div>');
            temp_id.id = id;
        } else {
            $('#'+'requests_content_'+temp_id.id).after('<div class="requests_content" id="requests_content_'+id+'"><a href='+'profile.php?user='+id+'><img src='+imgsrc+' width="60" height="60" class="senders_image"></a><a id="senders_name" href='+'profile.php?user='+id+'>'+firstname + ' ' +lastname+'</a><div id="acceptbutton">Accept</div><div id="rejectbutton">Reject</div></div>');
        }
    } 
}
```

Also, the PHP class that handles ajax requests has the following code

```
class RequestsAndAlerts {
public function hasRequests() {
    if(isset($_POST['checkrequest'])) {
        $current_user =  $_SESSION['cred_regiden'];
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE `ReqReceiver` = '$current_user'  ORDER BY `sentdatetime` DESC";
        $senders = array();
        if($query_run1 = mysql_query($query1)) {
            while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run1)) {
                $sender = $res['ReqSender'];
                array_push($senders, $sender);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($senders);
    }
}

public function sendRequestInfo() {
    if(isset($_POST['checkrequest2'])) {
        $sender = $_POST['checkrequest2'];
        $current_user = $_SESSION['cred_regiden'];
        $info_request_senders = array();
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `user_credentials` WHERE `cred_regiden` = '$sender'";
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `prof_image` WHERE `cred_regiden` = '$sender'";
        if($query_run1 = mysql_query($query1)) {
            while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run1)) {
                $info1 = $res['cred_regiden'];
                $info2 = $res['cred_fname'];
                $info3 = $res['cred_lname'];
                array_push($info_request_senders, $info1);
                array_push($info_request_senders, $info2);
                array_push($info_request_senders, $info3);
            }
        }
        if($query_run2 = mysql_query($query2)) {
            while($res2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run2)) {
                $info4 = $res2['image_dir'];
                $info5 = $res2['image_extension'];
                array_push($info_request_senders, $info4);
                array_push($info_request_senders, $info5);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($info_request_senders);
    }
}
$RAA = new RequestsAndAlerts;
$RAA->hasRequests();
$RAA->sendRequestInfo();
```

Now, I want to extract the data of people who has sent current user a friend request. For testing purpose I sent the user1 two friend requests from user2 and user3 and log in from user1 account, when I press requests button, on first click user1's info div is at the top and user2's info div is at the bottom.. This is good up to here.. But when I click again, they swap places.. But they do it in irregular pattern. I don't want this to happen. I want the user1 to always be on the top and user2 to be on the bottom of him according to as whose request is sent first. But I did this in mysql.. I arranged the requests in DESC order in mysql.. It should have arranged the div as "user1 on top" and "user2 on bottom".. But this happens randomly.

I guess this is due to the fact that json_encode randomizes the indexes of array.. But I'm not sure.. Help me guys... Just point out where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your multiple ajax call.

Note that ajax is asynchronous HTTP request

For example you have user1 and user2, in the for loop first ajax call will be initialized for getting the user1 details, hence ajax is a asynchronous it will not wait for  that requst. Tt will send next the ajax request immediately for getting the user2 results.
If request 2 completes before req1 .Then you will get the above error.

**Solution:**

   1. Get the user details in the first ajax call itself.

Or

   2 .Make the second ajax call as a synchronous.

I choose the first option.